# Unable to save file to NTFS partition from Windows

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab

I changed the `fstab` entry for my Windows (NTFS) partition to

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E87231007230D552 /windows-partition auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,permissions,users,auto,exec,umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

and I have softlinked my `~/Downloads` directory to `/windows-partition/Downloads`.

Now I can't write to that partition from Windows. Chrome says

> Cannot save to `D:\Downloads\` due to insufficient permissions

Is the `umask=0022` causing this issue? How can I keep permissions 755 in that partition and still be able to write to it from windows?

**EDIT** output of `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=a4245603-eb5d-43f6-9e04-edf1eb4ffe2e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=5d734581-cd49-46a1-9b87-a34446e7c400 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E87231007230D552 /windows-partition auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,permissions,users,auto,exec,umask=0022,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9426797226795668 /mnt/9426797226795668 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-udisks-auth 0 0
```

I also tried removing the permissions and umask  by changing the line for the Windows partition to:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E87231007230D552 /windows-partition auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,auto,exec 0 0
```

But it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: please perform `cat /etc/fstab`. Let's check how this fs it's mounted

Comment: @MarcosRocha I've added the o/p to the question

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to have been solved by giving the Windows session user the **Full Control** permission and taking ownership of it via the **Directory Properties -> Security Tab** in Windows.

I'm not sure if this counts as an Ask Ubuntu question anymore but since the problem started with a dual-boot, I'm gonna keep it here.